# Convert MySQL date time to Javascript Date.UTC format (useful for Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime, highcharts

Been breaking my head for the past couple of hours to solve a tiny issue in my Highcharts chart with a timeline, so here is my solution. Use it to your benefit.

The issue is that you can't just use the timestamp from an MySQL database (format: Y-m-d H:i:s) in the Highchart script as the Javascript Date.UTC counts the months differently... minus 1 so from January = 0 to December = 11 ***arrggg***

I've tried several proposed solutions for a conversion directly in the MySQL query but noticed that this resulted in incorrect results, so I abandoned that approach and went for a little PHP based function instead:

```
function format_as_jsDateUTC( $timestamp )
{
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp ); 
    $ret = $dt->format('Y, '); 
    $ret .= $dt->format('n')-1 == 0 ? 0 : $dt->format('n')-1;  
    $ret .= $dt->format(', j, G, i, s');
    /** 
     * [Y] full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
     * [n] numeric representation of a month, without leading zero, minus 1 for usage in Javascript (from January = 0 to December = 11)
     * [j] day of the month without leading zeros
     * [G] 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros
     * [i] minutes with leading zeros
     * [s] seconds with leading zeros
     */  
    return $ret;
}

echo format_as_jsDateUTC( '2017-01-05 09:08:07' );
// results in: 2017, 0, 5, 9, 08, 07
```

If anyone has any improvements or does know a correct way for achieving this in directly in my SELECT query then I'm always interested to hear as I can only learn from the feedback :)

Last but not least - in the jQuery code for my zoomable Highchart spline chart I used it as:

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo format_as_jsDateUTC( $stats['date'] ); ?>)
```

See also the full Highcharts code (without the PHP as it's on JSFiddle) at: http://jsfiddle.net/golabs/hfj6mug1/

Comment: Convert your `$timestamp` to epoch time, multiply by 1,000 (php converts to seconds, javascript uses milliseconds). so, `strtotime($timestamp) * 1000` will give you a usable javascript timestamp for Highcharts.

Comment: Tested it and that works smoothly :)

Just had to change it into  `( strtotime($timestamp)+3600 ) * 1000` to correct for the timezone. 

In the Highchart the line becomes: `pointStart: <?php echo format_as_jsDateUTC( $stats['date'] ); ?>` instead of `pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo format_as_jsDateUTC( $stats['date'] ); ?>)`.

When I won't find a way to format the seconds away in the labels on the Highchart then I might stick to my function as I can then force the seconds to be 0 so they don't show up in the labels.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC if you're having issues with timezones.  Any formatting needs to remove seconds should be pretty thoroughly covered with the various `formatter` functions, and the various date format settings. For more specific pointers, set up a fiddle that shows which things you need help formatting (best to start a new post for that though)